# Reuse prepared statement with optional condition

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, binding, prepared-statement

I am using one pretty complex prepared statement with various conditions in the WHERE clause and at one point I actually need the same statement with one more specific condition. Creating two different statements is a bad approach since both share most of their query string and when I update one I would have to update the other one as well. So far I tried using this:

```
SELECT columns
FROM tables
WHERE manyConditions AND (specificColumn = ? OR ? = NULL)
```

In this scenario I could bind one arbitrary argument and NULL to render the specific condition useless for queries which don't need it (`$pdo->execute([/* ... */, -1, null])`) while still being able to filter by `specificColumn` when binding a proper value and something that is not NULL (`$pdo->execute([/* ... */, 'specific value', true])`).

This is a really dirty way to prevent code duplication which forces me to bind two more variables in most cases.

Is there a more elegant approach to prevent code duplication?

Comment: Please leave some constructive feedback on why you're downvoting this question - maybe there is something to improve it?

Comment: don't be sad about downvoting I had the same experience and I never got any answer...

Comment: Downvoters the least you can do is to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very good question from a thoughtful programmer.

I'd say there is no equally elegant and simple solution. But I can offer a couple of approaches and you can decide which one is best for you.

1. You can use named placeholders and keep emulation mode turned on. In this case you will have to bind every variable only once. However, overall writing will remain the same as for named placeholders you have to repeat each name three times wither way.
2. As it was suggested in the now deleted answer, you could use conditional query building, something like

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT columns FROM tables WHERE manyConditions";
   $params = [$a,$b,$c];
   if (!empty($d)) {
       $sql .= " AND specificColumn = ?";
       $params[] = $d;
   }
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute($params)
   ```